# How to debug standard c library functions like printf?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, libc

I wanted to debug printf function, so when I step inside the printf function (gdb debugger) it showed me this:

```
__printf (format=0x80484d0 " my name is Adam") at printf.c:28
28  printf.c: No such file or directory.
```

What is the meaning of this?

And when I again started step then there are a lot more statements like this.

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Why do you want to debug printf? Do you expect bugs hiding there?

Comment: You should assume that system-provided functions, especially core ones such as `printf()`, are fault-free and that the problem is in your code using it, not in the function itself.  If you're using a modern compiler, make sure you're compiling with as many warning options as possible, and that you don't even try to run the code while there are any warnings from it.  (Using GCC, I require `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes …` to be clean, even with code from SO questions. Occasionally code from SO has to be treated differently, but not often.)

Comment: Are there not debug versions of the libs?

Comment: What is your OS? You need to install "glibc-debug" package. Exact package name depends on the OS you are using.

Comment: If you're curious still (and slightly off topic), read this blog: http://blog.hostilefork.com/where-printf-rubber-meets-road/ It's quite a detailed look at how `printf` eventually writes a character out.

Comment: Stepping through libraries is a great way to improve your understanding. I  would have thought that obvious in the context,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's pretty clear. There is a place where the *gdb* expects the source code to be, so download *glibc*'s source code and put it there. I think the error message contains the full path.

If it's a linux distro it's fairly simple in fact because usually source packages are shipped too. Otherwise you need to find the source code yourself, note that it MUST be exactly the same that was used to compile the c library components, not just the same version because distributors often make changes to the sources.

Comment: not quite as easy as it sounds: needs to be *exactly* the same source code as was used to compile the library. And usually, that means you'd want to get your OS's / distro's debug symbol and source code package :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller If it's a linux distro it's fairly simple in fact because usually source packages are shipped too. It hitnk I will put the first part of this comment in the answer, and I didn't say it was easy, just that the error message is clear about what the problem is.

Comment: It sounds quite difficult... :(  I use Clion on Ubuntu and click "step into" gives me assemble code.

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, GDB was unable to find the source file.

For the C runtime libraries, Linux distributions may provide a *debuginfo* RPM that you can install, which may allow GDB to view the files. For example:

> ```
> $ yum search glibc-debuginfo
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> glibc-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package glibc
> glibc-debuginfo-common.x86_64 : Debug information for package glibc
> ```
>
> ...

The `glibc` package and the `glibc-debuginfo` are a matched pair. There is no explicit dependency, but `glibc-debuginfo` package won't work unless it is matched with the same version of `glibc`.

If you have the sources unpacked somewhere, but not where GDB is expecting them to be, you can attempt to use either the `directory` or the `set substitute-path` command to let GDB know where the sources are.

The `directory` command tells GDB to prepend a prefix ahead of any source file path it is attempting to find. For example, if the source tree is actually located under the `/tmp`, you could use:

```
(gdb) directory /tmp
```

The `set substitute-path` command is used to tell GDB to replace a matching prefix in a source file path with a different path prefix. For example, if the compiled source file was in `/build/path/source.c`, but in debugging the source file is actually in `/usr/home/alice/release-1.1/source.c`, then you could use:

```
(gdb) set substitute-path /build/path /usr/home/alice/release-1.1
```

The command assumes that you are only specifying a complete path names, so it won't perform the substitution on `/build/pathological/source.c`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the debugger to show you the code that was compiled into the binaries you're using, you need the original code somewhere.

You don't seem to have that, so your debugger can't find it.

Notice that you usually *do not* want to debug the source code of your std library functions, but only the way they are being called. For that, the usual "debug symbol" packages of your operating systems are optimal.

Comment: Nice remark. It's like the OP suspect the bug is in the standard library, when it's highly likely in his code. But, perhaps what the OP want's is to check how these functions work.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi @  Marcus Müller Hi guys, wanna ask a question here. If I understand correctly, there are 3 kinds of files here: 1. C text source code 2. C binary source code 3. C binary source code with debug information. So I can debug type 1 and 3 but no 2, am I right?

Comment: no, you don't understand correctly: "binary source code" doesn't exist. That's self-contradicting. What you mean is "1. C source code, 2. Machine Code 3. Machine Code with Debug Information". You can debug all three, but differently.