# Not able to debug C programs in vscode iso99_scanf.c error

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.0.4.
I am trying to debug my C program using inbuilt Debugger option in vscode 1.44.2.
But as soon as I enter the scanf part or any input part of the code I get this error about file not found.
This is the message I get:

*Unable to open 'isoc99_scanf.c': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/stdio-common/isoc99_scanf.c' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/stdio-common/isoc99_scanf.c').*

I already have glibc-source installed using Synaptic Package Manager.

Please help me with this problem.

[File not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ESHM.png)

[text in the notification about error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Joxw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug standard c library functions like printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662035/how-to-debug-standard-c-library-functions-like-printf)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't, I already have glibc-source installed using synaptic package manager. Am I supposed to copy it somewhere?

Comment: It's explained there. Either copy it to `/build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/stdio-common/isoc99_scanf.c` or use `set substitute-path`.

Comment: I have searched every way I can, there is no such directory like this.

Comment: There isn't. You have to create it.... Or at best  use `substitute-path` to redirect your debugger.

Comment: Can you please help me with adding the substitute path... I don't know how to that.

Comment: The documentation about [vscode and debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference) and the [debugger option substitute-path](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html) is rather long, there's nothing better I could write here. Read them.