# Having problems with gdb

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, gdb

It says it can't find a certain file or directory (fxstat.c). I have tried installing glibc as some posts on the internet suggested but it did not work.

Here is the version:

```
GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2+b3) 8.2.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "aarch64-linux-gnu".
```

And the error message:

```
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0xda0: file ProbZC.cpp, line 10.
Starting program: /home/danielnyong66/Codeforces-And-LeetCode-Solutions/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at ProbZC.cpp:10
10          cin >> tests;
(gdb) n
__GI___fxstat (vers=<optimized out>, fd=<optimized out>, buf=0x7fffffef38) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64/fxstat.c:35
35      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64/fxstat.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) n
1
2
__GI___fxstat (vers=<optimized out>, fd=<optimized out>, buf=0x7fffffee68) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64/fxstat.c:35
35      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64/fxstat.c
(gdb) n
15
__lseek64 (fd=<optimized out>, offset=-1, whence=1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/lseek64.c:36
36      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/lseek64.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) n
[Inferior 1 (process 1212) exited normally]
```

I had a desktop with the same version of gdb running wsl (debian), I had compiled the program there and never had this problem, or even seen this error before. I am using an arm64, chromeos pc which kind of supports linux. This might be a system issue, however how do I fix this?

EDIT: With tink's suggestion, I add the path of the missing source, but it's just internal files, I still get the same result, my program just halts abruptly.

EDIT II: As G.M suggested here's is a sample source it doesn't matter what file it is.

```
1   #include<iostream>
  1 
  2 int main() {
  3         std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
  4 }
```

A different message now:

```
(gdb) list
1       #include<iostream>
2
3       int main() {
4               std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
5       }
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x9ec: file hello_word.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/danielnyong66/Codeforces-And-LeetCode-Solutions/hello 

Breakpoint 1, main () at hello_word.cpp:4
4               std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S:94
94      ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
```

It looks for files that are not in my program and shows an error when it can't find them.
This is the original file I was debugging: https://repl.it/join/iyqwodtx-danyxng

Edit: Backtrace...

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x9ec: file hello_word.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/danielnyong66/Codeforces-And-LeetCode-Solutions/hello 

Breakpoint 1, main () at hello_word.cpp:4
4               std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S:94
94      ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S:94
#1  0x0000007ff7f4ee58 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x0000005555555a00 in main () at hello_word.cpp:4
```

Comment: do you actually need to debug through the system libraries or are you trying to debug your own code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955609/include-source-code-of-malloc-c-in-gdb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662035/how-to-debug-standard-c-library-functions-like-printf/45662060#45662060

Comment: Use gdb to test and debug your application that built in debug mode!

Comment: @AlanBirtles It shows me that error when debugging my own code and then crashes. I can't use the debugger for anything thats why I am posting here.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `"...and then crashes"`.  Is it a segfault, abort, or what?  Can you get a call stack trace?

Comment: @G.M. sorry it shows me that then hangs. It exits the process, what I posted above is exactly what happens. I start up gdb, press next it hangs and shows me that message, I press next again it shows me the second message and then it stops running the program. So far tink 's suggestion seems promising.

Comment: @tink I have made progress but unfortunately it's a different problem, I can now see the internal files but then nothing changes, it still stops the process after stepping through those files, and ignores my own files. Also this doesn't happen all the time sometimes it debugs normally with the same source code.

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve] showing the code being debugged.  Re. `"Also this doesn't happen all the time sometimes it debugs normally with the same source code"`: I suspect you have undefined behaviour somewhere in your code.

Comment: @G.M. I think it may have to do with my system. What do you think?

Comment: The sample program [from G.M.] _can't_ segfault if you've built it normally. But, if you run under `gdb` and _do_ get a segfault, use the `tb` command to get a stack traceback.

Comment: @CraigEstey I did, just showed my that the file it's looking for does not exist.

Comment: Gdb is behaving correctly, a crash has happened inside a system library, it's telling you it doesn't have the source code for that library, if you move up the stack trace into your own code it will offer you more information. Your actual problem is that your system is very broken, maybe a mix of gcc and libstdc++ versions?

Comment: @AlanBirtles It is likely that my system is broken. But the stack trace information is the same, the main function of my program, the basic_ostream insertion operator function, and the c strlen function, where it breaks. Also how can I post this that it doesn't get marked as duplicate, I need help on this.

Comment: What do you want help with? Fixing the crash or with GDB? The crash is some misconfiguration of your system. If you want help with GDB what do you expect it to do? Its working as expected, its stopped at the point where the segfault occurred and wont allow you to keep running as the program has crashed

Comment: maybe with my system. If there was actually a Segfault how come all my executables run just fine? Work as expected, that's why I suspect it to be gdb.